# How to access webpages only accessible from some region?

Tags: networking

There are some webpages only accessible from a particular country. But I have heard that they can still be accessed from outside the country, for example by VPN, proxy, .... I wonder how to do these specifically in Ubuntu and Windows 7 respectively?

Do I have to look for some server by myself and if yes, where I can find some?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to find working proxy (in allowed country) and then (assuming that u use firefox) Go through->File->preferencies->advenced->web->settings and set it there.

The best way to find it is to search "proxy list" in google. However a lot of them are unworking. And you shouldn't type anywhere your password without being sure that you're using secure connection.